# Don't repeat yourself or be more clear by repeating yourself?

Tags: c#, dry, code-duplication

I have this base class below:

```
abstract class RequiredString {

    protected readonly string _text;

    public RequiredString(string name, string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            throw new TextEmptyException($"The '{name}' field is required");

        _text = text;
    }

    public RequiredString(string name, string text, int maxLength): this(name, text)
    {
        if (_text.Length > maxLength)
            throw new TextLengthTooLongException($"The '{name}' field length is too long ({text.Length}/{maxLength})");
    }

    public static implicit operator string(RequiredString field)
    {
        return field._text;
    }

}
```

I have dozen of classes that inherit from the base class. All have a maximum length:
For example:

```
public sealed class Email : RequiredString
{
    private const int Length = 255;
    private const string Name = "Email";

    public Email(string text) : base(Name, text, Length)
    {
        try
        {
            new MailAddress(_text);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            throw new EmailFormatException($"'{_text}' field is not a valid email string", ex);
        }

    }

    public static implicit operator Email(string text)
    {
        return new Email(text);
    }
}
```

Let's say the reader checks the Email class and didn't see the base class.

Is it clear to him/her that the length checking occurs in the base class? 
Does it make sens or should I put the length checking in every inherited class?
How would you refactor that code to make it cleaner?

Thank you!

Comment: Having `Length` field in the inherited class, but checking it in the base class is confusing. I would expect it to be checked in the inherited class if I see it there. Also where is `maxLength` defined?

Comment: Consider making `Length` an abstract readonly property in the base class.

Comment: `Is it clear to him/her that the length checking occurs in the base class?` It is clear _enough_ yes, given it is passed to the base class.

Comment: You call base constructor. So reader should check the code of base class. It’s natural, nothing wrong with it. Not looking at the base constructor is the same as ignoring part of code: a reader is the only one to blame.

Comment: ...And while you are considering mjwills's proposal, also consider renaming it from `Length` to `MaxLength`.

Comment: Ok, I renamed Length to MaxLength
@mjwills, "consider making MaxLength as an abstract readonly property" => even though I only need it to throw TextLengthTooLongException in the constructor?

Comment: document your classes and you're good